# Unable to bind java script function with Panel's OnLoad event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, panel

I am in the initial stages in working with java script and I just wrote a small application in asp.net for using the Google Maps APIv3. I want to display the map in a panel. This is the code that I wrote but I have problem in binding the java script with the Panel's OnLoad event:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
  <title>Map Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      html{height:100%}
      body{height:100%; margin:0;padding:0}
      #map_can{height:100%}
    </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzawerwerQ55N500rxxxxdPNvMoQ74aRYO30Wo&sensor=true">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function init()
     {
       var mapoptions=
          {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.379064211298, 78.478946685791),
            zoom:8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
       var map=new  google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_can"),mapoptions);
     }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel  OnLoad="init()" ID="Panel1" runat="server" 
      style="z-index: 1; left: 37px; top: 59px; position: absolute; height: 273px; width: 565px">
      <div id="map_can" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
    </asp:Panel>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Error: `ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'init'`

I guess I am binding it the wrong way. Suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Panel `OnLoad` property is for setting *server side* handler for Load event (it should be method in your page class).

There is no way of setting *client side* load event on Panel control as it generates DIV element (and DIV element doesn't support load event).

A primitive way out of this is to use *client side* load event of BODY element:

```
<body onload="init();" >
    ...
</body>
```

But a lot better way is to wait for DOM readiness to invoke a function. An easy and cross browser way of doing this is usage of library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var mapoptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.379064211298, 78.478946685791),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new  google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_can"),mapoptions);  
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Right now I am not thinking of learning JQuery. So I can load the function in the onload event of BODY and write the div tag in the panel and it works. But if I have few more java script functions, then how can I specify them in the onload event of BODY?

Comment: @Cdeez What is stopping you from combining all those function in one or creating one general init function which will call all the others (also remember about global namespace poluting here). I would need to know a lot more about your page flow to suggest proper architecture approach.

Comment: My question in the comment was a generic one in having multiple functions. Though I havent still planned how ill be going forward later, but your comment has given me an idea how to deal it. Ill get back to you here, if I have an issue. Thanks.